# How to obtain three level relationship in LARAVEL?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have 3 tables, User, Group and GroupUser. I want to get user details (user table) who are added in group. Here is the talbe structure i am following.

```
user
+--------------+----------------------+
| id    | name      | user_statu      |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 1     | John doe  | ofline          |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 2     | John carry| away            |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 3     | jimn carry| online          |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 4     | adward    | online          |
+--------------+----------------------+


group
+--------------+----------------------+
| id    | title     | status          |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 1     | group1    | actie           |
+--------------+----------------------+
| 2     | group2    | acrive          |
+--------------+----------------------+


group_users
+--------------+-------------------+
| id    | user_id   | group_id     |
+--------------+-------------------+
| 1     | group1    | 1            |
+--------------+-------------------+
| 2     | group2    | 1            |
+--------------+-------------------+
```

> Model

**Group.php**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\GroupUser', 'group_id');
}
```

> What i am trying is:

```
$group = Group::with("users")->where([
                        ['id', '=', $user_id],
                        ['status', '=', 1],
                    ])->first();
$group->users
```

**I am getting**

```
"users": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 237,
        "group_id": 1,
        "status": 1,
    },
```

i also want to get `user name` along.

Please correct me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do here is many-to-many relationships (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

In your model Group.php:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'group_users', 'group_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Then when you do `$group->users`, it will contain the model `User` not `GroupUser`. You can now get the name from here.

Answer (score 0):

use code :

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'group_users', 'group_id', 'user_id');
}
```